# How to add a route to MVC3 converting part the URL to an argument?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, global-asax

How can I add a route that would catch all URLs pointing to a controller so that all arguments after the controller name gets transformed into a single argument string?

I need this sort of mapping:

```
URL /Image/foo.png     -> Controller: Image, Action: Index, argument "foo.png"
URL /Image/A/foo.png   -> Controller: Image, Action: Index, argument "/A/foo.png"
URL /Image/A/B/foo.png -> Controller: Image, Action: Index, argument "/A/B/bar.png"
```

This is my action inside `ImageController`

```
public ImageResult Index(string file)
{
    // foo bar
}
```

This is what I tried

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "Image/{file*}", new { controller = "Image", action = "Index" });
```

URL `/Image/baz.png` works, file is "baz.png". URL `/Image/A/foo.png` does not work, my action is not hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. It should be

```
"Image/{*file}"
```

That way `file` will contain everyting in the URL following `Image/`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I love it when I can close an issue with a one character commit :D.